# Separar string e numeros (Ex.: 00oy285dase556 - num1=00, num2=285, num3=556)

Tags: c

Preciso criar um módulo de leitura, a taxa variável, de valores numéricos na porta
Serial, a receber uma string de inteiros, intercaladas por letras e usar as letras como separador para obter apenas os numeros em linguagem C. (Ex.: 00oy285dase556 - num1=00, num2=285, num3=556)

Comment: Defina melhor seu problema. A quantidade de números é indefinida? Só devem ser considerados números inteiros ou podem existir números reais? É permitido utilizar alocação dinâmica de memória? Poste o código que já tentou fazer. Leia [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode partir de algo do tipo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main() {
    int i=0, j=0, k=0, l, num[10];
    char buffer[256], aux[20];
    printf ("Informe a entrada: ");
    fgets (buffer, 255, stdin);
    while (buffer[i] != '\0') {
        while (buffer[i] != '\0' && !isdigit(buffer[i]))
            i++;
        if (buffer[i] != '\0') {
            j = 0;
            while (buffer[i] != '\0' && isdigit(buffer[i]))
                aux[j++] = buffer[i++];
            aux[j] = '\0';
            num[k++] = atoi (aux);
        }
    }
    for (l=0; l<k; l++)
        printf ("numero[%d] = %d\n",l, num[l]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: muito agradecida!